# How to install package without administrator password?

Tags: macos, package-management, ms-teams

For example i am installing ms teams. It is definitly known that it does not require admin permissions. But package requests it. Of course they could install some backdoor even for user, but for admin that is dangerous twice.
The same with pkg and with brew (because it installs cask which is that pkg).

So, is there a way to install for user but avoid entering password?

may be there is a sandboxing way?

Answer (score 1):

## pkgutil

Extract the files from the `.pkg` file with the built in macOS command [`pkgutil`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pkgutil/):

```
pkgutil --expand <pkg-path> <dir-path>
```

Then manually place the extracted files as needed.

See also [Install as non-admin user when the installer requires admin permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48649)

Comment: That does not work anymore from v13 (Ventura).

Comment: @EricPlaton, `pkgutil` still works on the latest versions of macOS, including 14.2.1. You may need to install the Xcode Command Lines Tools or Xcode application to get `pkgutil`. Please [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if this does not work for you.

Comment: From Ventura the security model has changed, and the usual command you rightly suggest here does not work anymore. Just tried again with a couple .pkg, and getting the unhelpful cryptic `Could not open package for expansion: ...pkg`. I have tried to find the links (on SE) that give more information, but could not dig them out yet.

On the other hand, simply untaring the pax archive from packages just works fine. E.g. `tar xvfz xxx.pkg/Contents/Archive.pax.gz` gets the app folder.

Comment: Good to know. So this suggests *some* packages may not work with `pkgutil`. That is a bug that should be [reported to Apple](https://apple.com/feedback).